# CI load properties by default

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use `Codeigniter` Framework, and I set my program to load header and footer by default when i load the view method. In the header file I have properties like: site name, description etc.. Those proprieties fetch from the DB. Now the problem is that I need to set them every time I call the view method.
How can I set them by default correctly?

Comment: You can achieve this by creating a MY_Controller that extends CI_Controller, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171046/data-available-for-all-views-in-codeigniter/16171508#16171508

Comment: I succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider upvoting the original answer I linked to above :-)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation.. :(

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above, you should extend the Controller. I do something very simular to this, and this is my code, which is found on "MY_Controller.php" within the ./application/core directory.

```
public function show_view($view, $data = array())
{
    // Database connection here
    // add anything to the $data array

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view($view, $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Now, instead of loading a view from the controller like this;

```
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

I do this;

```
$this->show_view('view', $data);
```

**FYI. I call the function "show_view" to avoid name conflicts.**