# Codeigniter and code repetition DRY

Tags: php, codeigniter

Need best practice to avoid code repetition in Codeigniter Class methods. Is this even possible in my situation? If I somehow assign global variable, I still need to pass $data array to view, so maybe some kind of global $data array?

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

}

public function login()
{
    $data['title'] = 'User Login';
    $data['home_url'] = base_url();
    $data['current_url'] = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $data['login_url'] = LOGIN_URL;
    $data['register_url'] = REGISTER_URL;

    $this->parser->parse("login.tpl", $data);
}

public function register()
{
    $data['title'] = 'User Register';
    $data['home_url'] = base_url();
    $data['current_url'] = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $data['login_url'] = LOGIN_URL;
    $data['register_url'] = REGISTER_URL;

    $this->parser->parse("register.tpl", $data);
}
```

Comment: Check this answer on globally available data to view: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171508/989234

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
private $data = array();

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->data['home_url'] = base_url();
    $this->data['current_url'] = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $this->data['login_url'] = LOGIN_URL;
    $this->data['register_url'] = REGISTER_URL;
}

public function login()
{
    $this->data['title'] = 'User Login';

    $this->parser->parse("login.tpl", $this->data);
}

public function register()
{
    $this->data['title'] = 'User Register';

    $this->parser->parse("register.tpl", $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems legit.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
public function login()
{
    login_or_register("login");
}

public function register()
{
    login_or_register("register");
}

public function login_or_register(type)
{
    $data['title'] = 'User ' . ucfirst($type);
    $data['home_url'] = base_url();
    $data['current_url'] = $this->uri->segment(1);

    $data['login_url'] = LOGIN_URL;
    $data['register_url'] = REGISTER_URL;

    $this->parser->parse($type . ".tpl", $data);
}
```