# How to send $data array type variable to all controllers so that it will show on all views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have a problem that I am making the dynamic menu so that I have to send `$data['coursemenu']` array type variable which I am fetching from

```
$data['coursemenu']=$this->CourseModel->fetchParentCourses();
```

and send this data to all controllers so that it is common for all functions of the controller after that it'll send to view which is common for headers which I had included in this way in all functions like this way.

```
    $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('mainpages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('common/footer', $data);
```

Comment: You should start by removing any irrelevant tags. Are you using CI 2 or 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data available for all views in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171046/data-available-for-all-views-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Add model code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i already checked this is there any other way to send data.

Answer (score 1):

first of all create a new file `MY_Controller` extends `CI_Controller` in `application/core` directory
create just a function `public function __construct()` in it and process your data there. for the result you want to use in all your controllers use name something like `$this->User`

here is my code for example
**MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Options_model');
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        if (user_logged_in()) {
            $this->User = user_logged_in();
        }
        foreach ($this->Options_model->get_global_settings() as $result) {
            $this->global_data[$result->option_key] = $result->option_value;
        }
    }
}
```

for my view simply I use it
**Header_view.php**

```
<title><?php echo isset($page_title) ? $page_title . $this->global_data['site_name'] : $this->global_data['dashboard_title'] . ' &#8211; ' . $this->global_data['site_name']; ?></title>
```

Or this one

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hi <?php echo $this->User['first_name']; ?>,Welcome to your dashboard</a>
```

Comment: One **Important** thing that i forgot is in your controller. you should extend them from `MY_Controller` Not `CI_Controller`

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother.